# Classifying tensor powers of tangent bundles as pullbacks of appropriate tangent bundles

Tags: differential-topology

Assume we are given a smooth manifold $M$ and let $TM^{\otimes r}, r>1,$ be some
tensor power of its tangent bundle.

Is there any general observation/result
saying when there exists a manifold $N$ and a smooth map $f: M \rightarrow N$ such that the pull back bundle $f^*TN$ is isomorphic to
$TM^{\otimes r}$?

This question is just a result of curiosity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the idea is the folk fact that the universal space and universal stable ** bundle can be taken to be a manifold and its tangent bundle [see proof below ]

take r=3 and let M have dim d
then N should have dimension 3d

any [stable] bundle [like the tensor power] over a d dim space [like M]  can be induced by a map into the universal space by a map which goes into the d skeleton of the universal space

the d skeleton of the universal space can be embedded in R^2d and thickened to a manifold nghd to obtain a parallizable manifold

the universal bundle over the d skeleton can be reduced to a d dim bundle using obstruction theory

the total space of this bundle pulled back to the  thickened nghd will be the N of dim 3d

its tangent bundle is isomorphic to the universal bundle [because they are stably isomorphic]

the classifying map pulls the tangent bundle back to the required bundle

this proof works for r bigger but not immediately for r=2 [but mazur thickening theory should do this case]

dennis sullivan

**stable here means fibre dim bigger than dim base

Comment: D.S., why $\mathbb R^{2\cdot d}\ $ (so good), rather than only $\ \mathbb R^{2\cdot d+1}\,$ ?